How to dynamically pass column names using PySpark in Databricks when reading an input CSV file from an Azure container
I have a input file employee.csv stored in a container containing columns "Empid","Ename","Esalary"  and I created a target table in databicks delta lake with these 3 columns.
If I select only one column i.e "Empid"(I need to configure the  Empid column name in config.ini  configuration file) only that column data should be read from input file other columns values will be passed a null


you can do select after reading the csv file. df.select("<required_column_name>").

please add code which you tried so far

In order to get desired outcome, you can read the input file employee.csv as a DataFrame and select only the "Empid" column.
Then, rename the column to match the one specified in the configuration file (config.ini) using the withColumnRenamed function.
Finally, fill the other two columns with null values using the withColumn and lit functions.
I have tried the below approach:
csv_file_path = f"abfss://folder02@dilipstg.dfs.core.windows.net/newemp.csv"
df = spark.read.csv(csv_file_path, header=True)
df = df.select('Empid').withColumnRenamed('Empid', 'config_column')
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
df = df.withColumn('Ename', lit(None)).withColumn('Esalary', lit(None))
delta_path = "/FileStore/tables/Delta/employee"
df.write.format('delta').mode('overwrite').save(delta_path)

Results:
config_column   Ename   Esalary
1   null    null
2   null    null
3   null    null
4   null    null

